# php query without var=

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404

I'd like the end user of my website to be able to do something along the lines of: `example.com/user/user_name` to show the statistics of that user on a different website. In short, I'd like to be able to make queries in php without having the user do: `example.com/user/username=user_name` I also have no way of knowing all of the possible users. I guess this means I'd like to always redirect to the index, while preserving the querystring that doesn't have "var=" in it. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cna use the explode function in php. use it on the url slashes "/" and you get valid data to query. Remember to make it secure from sql injections.

EDIT
here you go:

```
$url = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo 'user = '.$url[count($url)-1].'<br />
username = '.$url[count($url)-2];
```

EDIT 2

yeah you need to use .htaccess
unless you wanna get away with the questionmark
http://example.com?/user/username

EDIT 3

if you use apache you can make all traffic go through index.php with following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# always run through the indexfile
RewriteRule .$ index.php
```

Then if you want some folder to not go through to index.php, you add a htaccess file in that folder with:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Comment: I understand that. I just don't know how to do that without having a directory for every possible username. I guess my question is, how do I always redirect to index.php, and preserve the user's query?

Comment: Thank you! It is just what I was looking for! (edit 3 is what I used)

Comment: Well, your suggestion did work, but I ended up changing it to `RedirectMatch ^/id/(.*) /index.php?id=$1`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to still have the script be `somepage.php?username=user_name` and then have in your `.httaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/user/(.*) somepage.php?username=$1
```

This way you can still get the variable with `$_GET['username']` but it looks nice to the user.